# Takes data from php and phpmailer

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, phpmailer

I have a form and I inserted the resizing in my image upload. The problem is how to take the reduced image from the phpmailer. because now the image that sends is the image in full size. what I have to change in phpmailer to take the image with a small size? I have tried to shift name="menu1" near a  but the form give me a error

```js
async function compressImage (event, useWebWorker) {
    var file = event.target.files[0]
    var logDom
    if (useWebWorker) {
      logDom = document.querySelector('#web-worker-log')
    } else {
      logDom = document.querySelector('#main-thread-log')
    }
    document.getElementById('preview').src = URL.createObjectURL(file)

    logDom.innerHTML = 'Source image size:' + (file.size / 1024 / 1024).toFixed(2) + 'mb'
    console.log('input', file)
    console.log('ExifOrientation', await imageCompression.getExifOrientation(file))
    var options = { maxSizeMB: 1, maxWidthOrHeight: 1024, useWebWorker: useWebWorker }
    const output = await imageCompression(file, options)
    logDom.innerHTML += ', output size:' + (output.size / 1024 / 1024).toFixed(2) + 'mb'
    console.log('output', output)
    const downloadLink = URL.createObjectURL(output)
    logDom.innerHTML += '&nbsp;<a href="' + downloadLink + '" download="' + file.name + '">download compressed image</a>'
    document.getElementById('preview-after-compress').src = downloadLink
    // await uploadToServer(output)
  }

  function uploadToServer (file) {
    var formData = new FormData()
    formData.append('image', file)
    return fetch('http://localhost/image-upload-api', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: formData
    })
  }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/browser-image-compression@1.0.6/dist/browser-image-compression.js">
```

```css
 <style>
    table, th, td {
        border: 0px solid black;
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    td {
        vertical-align: top;
        width: 0%;
    }
    img {
        max-width: 0%;
    }
</style>
```

```html
   <div class="form-group was-validated">
        <label class="control-label">Menu1</label>
        <input type="file" id="web-worker" name="menu1" accept=".jpg,.jpeg,.pdf,.png" onchange="compressImage(event, true)" required>
        <p id="web-worker-log"></p>
       </div>
       <div class="progress">
        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated" role="progressbar" style="width: 0%" aria-valuenow="100" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
       </div>
       <table>
    <tr>
   
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><img id="preview" /></td>
        <td><img id="preview-after-compress"  /></td>
    </tr>
        
</table>
```

```html
<?php

    $nome        = $_POST["nome-locale"];
    $email       = $_POST["email"];
    $telefono    = $_POST["telefono"];
    $indirizzo   = $_POST["indirizzo"];
    $civico      = $_POST["civico"];
    $citta       = $_POST["citta"];
    $provincia   = $_POST["provincia"];
    $cap         = $_POST["cap"];
    $titolare    = $_POST["titolare"];
 $cf          = $_POST["codice_fiscale"]; 
    $declaration = isset($_POST["declaration"]) ? $_POST['declaration'] : 'No';
    $newsletter  = isset($_POST["newsletter"]) ? $_POST['newsletter'] : 'No';
    $data        = date('d-m-Y'); 


    $body = "<br>nome-locale:" . $nome . "<br>Email:" . $email . "<br>TelefonoLocale:" . $telefono . "<br>Indirizzo:" . $indirizzo . "<br>Civico:" . $civico . "<br>Città:" . $citta . "<br>Provincia:" . $provincia . "<br>Cap:" . $cap . "<br>Nome titolare:" . $titolare . "<br>CF:" . $cf . "<br>Declaration:" . $declaration . "<br>newsletter:" . $newsletter;


    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

    require 'PHPMailer/src/Exception.php';
    require 'PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
    require 'PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php';
    // Instantiation and passing `true` enables exceptions
    $mail = new PHPMailer(true);

    $mail->isSMTP(); // Send using SMTP
    $mail->Host       = 'x'; // Set the SMTP server to send through
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true; // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username   = 'x'; // SMTP username
    $mail->Password   = 'x'; // SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'x'; // Enable TLS encryption; `PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS` also accepted
    $mail->Port       = x; // TCP port to connect to

    if (array_key_exists('menu1', $_FILES) && array_key_exists('menu2', $_FILES)) {
        try {
            //Server settings
            // First handle the upload
            // Don't trust provided filename - same goes for MIME types
            // See http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php#114004 for more thorough upload validation
            $menu1_filename = $_FILES['menu1']['name'];
            $menu2_filename = $_FILES['menu1']['name'];

            $menu1 = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), hash('sha256', $menu1_filename));
            $menu2 = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), hash('sha256', $menu2_filename));

            if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['menu1']['tmp_name'], $menu1) &&
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES['menu2']['tmp_name'], $menu2)) {
                // Upload handled successfully
                // Now create a message
                //Recipients
                $mail->setFrom('feed@vaimenu.it', $data);
                $mail->addAddress('feed@vaimenu.it'); // Add a recipient
                $mail->isHTML(true); // Set email format to HTML
                $mail->Subject = ('Iscrizione: ' . $nome);
                $mail->Body = $body;
                $mail->AltBody = 'Iscrizione ricevuta da landing page';

                // Attach the uploaded file
                $mail->AddAttachment($menu1, $menu1_filename);
                $mail->AddAttachment($menu2, $menu2_filename);
                $mail->send();

                $mail->ClearAllRecipients();
                $mail->clearAddresses();
                $mail->ClearAttachments();

                $mail->isHTML(true);
                $mail->Subject = ('Benvenuto, ' . $nome);
                $mail->setFrom('feed@vaimenu.it', 'Vaimenu.it');
                $mail->addAddress($email);

                $message = file_get_contents('Benvenuto.html');
                $message = str_replace('%Nome%', $nome, $message);

                $mail->MsgHtml($message);

                if (!$mail->send()) {
                    $response['error']   = true;
                    $response['message'] = "Message could not be sent. Some thing went wrong Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
                } else {
                    $response['success'] = true;
                }
            } else {
                $response['error']   = true;
                $response['message'] = 'Failed to move file to ' . $menu1;
            }

            echo json_encode($response);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $response['error']   = true;
            $response['message'] = "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";

            echo json_encode($response);
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can compress image before sent email like :

```
$target = "./img/".basename($_FILES['fileuploaded']['name']);   
compressedImage($_FILES['fileuploaded']['tmp_name'],$target,75); //75 is quality of image
function compressedImage($source, $path, $quality) {

            $info = getimagesize($source);

            if ($info['mime'] == 'image/jpeg'){
                $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($source);

            }elseif ($info['mime'] == 'image/gif'){
                $image = imagecreatefromgif($source);

            }elseif ($info['mime'] == 'image/png'){ 
                $image = imagecreatefrompng($source);
            }

            imagejpeg($image, $path, $quality);
            return $path;

    }
```

Comment: Ok, but with my code, the image is already resized, my problem is how to take the image resized and send with phpmailer.  
I can't understand how to take the already resized file and not the full-size one

Comment: Ok! But the problem is that I can't understand what the new path is of that , can you look on my code . Before I take a IMG with name="menu1" but now I don't understand where is the new path

Comment: The variable `downloadLink` containe the url to image compressed, so you must use that for sent image.

Comment: Ok perfect! And now how I take this variable and send with phpmailer? An exemple ('menu1' $_FILES)

Comment: No Fabio, usi la variabile appendendola dopo il processo di compressione così si trasmette in php ed hai già il link. (comunque facevi prima a far tutto in php con il codice sopra)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208567/discussion-between-fabio-koichi-begnini-and-simone-rossaini).